# How to subtract two column values from two tables and insert in 3rd table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, subquery, sql-insert

I'm using SQlite

***Table A***: one column to store subtracted value(difference) ***Table B***: one column with unix timestamp(OFF_time)
***Table C***: one column with unix timestamp(ON_time)

HAVE to subtract timestamps of columns OFF_time and ON_time from tables B and C respectively and store in A.

This is what i tried:

```
 insert into A (difference) select B.OFF_time-C.ON_time from B,C;
```

[EDITED]

and got no error, but Table A is empty and not updated with the difference.

SAMPLE DATA:

TABLE C:
[ON_time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbCQf.png)

TABLE B:
[OFF_time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7H2M.png)

DESIRED OUPUT: TABLE A:

difference(column name in table A)

622

1024

608

398

458

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I doubt you really want a Cartesian product.

Comment: Your query, although its is logically wrong, it is syntactically correct. So it seems that the query you posted here is not responsible for this error. Check elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @forpas yes i found a typo and changed it now i have another issue:(

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added sample data and desired result. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() window function to join B and C:

```
insert into A (difference) 
select t1.OFF_time - t2.ON_time 
from (select *, row_number() over (order by OFF_time) rn from B) t1
inner join (select *, row_number() over (order by ON_time) rn from C) t2
on t2.rn = t1.rn;
```

Comment: WOW! thanks that worked. If you dont mind, can you explain what you did in simple terms?

Comment: In each of the tables B and C, row_number() returns the number of each row ordered by time. Then the 2 queries are joined based on this number: row 1 from B with row 1 from c, row 2 from B with row 2 from c and the 2 columns of the 2 tables are subtracted.

Comment: Thanks you so much.